# Giving keyboard inputs to a nohup program

Tags: ssh, nohup

I know that when doing some ssh, I can use the nohup command to prevent a program execution from halting when I close the ssh session.
However, I need to run a program that takes some keyboard input at the beginning. When I run it, I am prompted with several questions that I need to manually answer, then the program will actually start doing what it is meant to do and then I would like to close my connection and let it run in the background.
How can I do this? My ideal solution would be some sort of "persistent ssh session" or so, something that would allow me to start a program, give it inputs via keyboard, the program gives me terminal output, then I close the connection, open it again and still see the program running, its output and so on, like if I just opened it without disconnecting and reconnecting.

Is there any way to do such a thing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't that what `screen` or `tmux` do?

Comment: Wow! Screen actually does what I need. However, I am still having a problem. I open run screen, launch a command, then hit ctrl + a, then press d to detach. It returns to my previous session. If I use screen -r it restores everything. However, if I try to disconnect from ssh and then connect back, when I do screen -r it just says "There is no screen to be resumed". Am I doing something wrong?